# Оптимизация mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Похожий вопрос уже был задан другим пользователем, но ответ на него меня не устроил. 
Мне нужно выводить данные из таблицы (сортируя по дате, т.е. чем новее сообщении, тем оно выше). Логично предположить, что нужна сортировка по убыванию ORDER BY `my_date` ASC. Но ведь, когда мы добавляем в базу данные, то они добавляются в низ таблицы, значит для того, чтобы отсортировать по дате, достаточно просто начинать читать строки снизу. Как в mysql сделать так, чтобы начать выбирать строку снизу, а не сверху?                              (Можно ли так записать `LIMIT COUNT(*)-1`)?

Comment: > сортируя по дате, т.е. чем новее сообщении, тем оно выще

Тогда нужно, наоборот, делать `ORDER BY my_date DESC`

Comment: Без сортировки нельзя вообще!

Comment: а вы неправильно задаете вопрос, поэтому и не получаете правильный ответ.
что за формулировка "мне нужна сортировка по убыванию" в этом нет вопроса. как выбирать строку снизу а не сверху? и почему вы решили что они так хранятся в БД, это они так для вас отображаются.

Comment: @jmu согласен

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать создать индекс на my_date по убыванию.
Но без ORDER BY гарантии, что записи будут извлекаться в соответствии с этим индексом, нет.

Comment: Без сортировки ее гарантии вообще нет)

Answer (score 0):

В любой книжке по SQL и все производители баз данных пишут большими буквами для программистов, что "никто не гарантирует строгую последовательность записей в таблице", это важно знать, а то и id так начнут смотреть по последней записи.

Comment: Добавлю:
такой факт обусловлен тем что при записи в таблицу, субд записывает в свободную облость памяти, а эта облось может быть между двумя предыдущими записями, в том случае если какая та запись была удалена.

Comment: Ну дак а примари кей выставлен?

Comment: Обьясни про примарикей 4, 8 и 16 байтовым ячейка, которые и понятия не имеют про это, не тот уровень абстракции, при чтении из базы строк без сортировки, тебе выдается ответ так как оно лежит в файловой системе